# Conditional super() statement in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a class which get instantiated by super(). In super() I want to send parameter based on some condition. But if I place if statement before super(), typescript gives compilation error saying super() must be the first statement.
Is there any way I can achieve loading of the super class based on condition.

Here is the code which is not working. I want to pass/block dependencies parameter(ENGINE_MODEL) in  super() based on some condition.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Code:

```
export class CreateChrStructureNodeControlComponent extends StructureNodeControl {
    constructor(private changeRequestCreateService: CreateChangeRequestService) {
    if(some condition = 'SF')  //my logic
        super(changeRequestCreateService,
            PLANT,
            ENGINE_MODEL);
    else 
         super(changeRequestCreateService,
            PLANT)
      ;
    }
}
```

---

Superclass :

```
export class StructureNodeControl extends BaseTypeaheadControl<TypeahaedLookupTableItem> {
    constructor(changeRequestCreateService: CreateChangeRequestService, ...dependencies: string[]) {
        super(STRUCTURE_NODE,
            changeRequestCreateService.getStructureNodes,
            TypeahaedLookupTableItem,
            ...dependencies);
    }
```

Comment: P.S. You spelled `Typeahead` wrong in `TypeahaedLookupTableItem`.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), so that others can demonstrate your issue for themselves, and/or provide a link to a web IDE that shows the problem.  It might be a simple matter to refactor to a single `super()` with an inlined condition check, but without a reproducible example I wouldn't be able to test any answer I give.

Comment: This is fixed in [TypeScript 4.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#allowing-code-in-constructors-before-super). You can have code in your constructor before `super()`, just as long as it doesn’t reference `this` or `super`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the super parameter from a varargs string array to a regular old string array, then you can conditionally add dependencies to that array and filter out the disabled ones.

i.e. change the superclass to:

```
export class StructureNodeControl extends BaseTypeaheadControl<TypeahaedLookupTableItem> {
    constructor(changeRequestCreateService: CreateChangeRequestService, dependencies: string[]) {
        super(STRUCTURE_NODE,
            changeRequestCreateService.getStructureNodes,
            TypeahaedLookupTableItem,
            ...dependencies);
    }
```

and then in your subclass:

```
export class CreateChrStructureNodeControlComponent extends StructureNodeControl {
    constructor(private changeRequestCreateService: CreateChangeRequestService) {
   super(changeRequestCreateService,
         [
          PLANT,
          some_logic === 'SF' ? ENGINE_MODEL : null
         ].filter(Boolean) // get rid of the nulls
   );
}
```